# Encontrar coincidencias de elementos en 2 columnas distintas en Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2013, excel-2010

Hola buenas tardes comunidad. Tengo una duda de Excel

Tengo esta tabla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No encuentro la forma de contar la cantidad de veces que se repite la combinacion Argentina Alemania

Ya intente con la función contar.si.conjunto pero me devuelve la la cantidad de repeticiones en un solo sentido, es decir, me devuelve la cantidad de veces que argentina se enfrente a Alemania pero siendo argentina local y Alemania visitante o vice versa pero no logro que me devuelva la cantidad total de coincidencias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay más de una forma, pero continuando con tu idea, yo diría que hay que "sacarle la vuelta" a lo que mencionas ya habías avanzado. Prueba así:

```
=CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO(Tabla1[[#Todo];[Local]];"Argentina";Tabla1[[#Todo];[Visitante]];"Alemania")+CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO(Tabla1[[#Todo];[Local]];"Alemania";Tabla1[[#Todo];[Visitante]];"Argentina")
```

Por si acaso yo uso los puntos y comas como separador de argumentos/lista, si tú usas las comas, solo reemplaza por ellas. No olvides que no necesariamente copiando y pegando resulte tal cual deseas, trata, sobre todo de adaptar. Saludos.

Comment: Hola Abraham. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, es muy esclarecedora. Voy a adaptarla a mi problema y seguro lo soluciono
Saludos desde Argentina

Comment: Excelente, no dejes de comentar. Saludos.

Comment: Estoy probando el código que adjuntaste y aunque sirve, sirve parcialmente. Estoy releyendo la pregunta y no explique el problema del todo detallado
Tu código sirve pero siempre y cuando se busque un pais determinado en el rango, por ejemplo argentina o Alemania pero si dentro del rango hay otra combinación de paises que se repiten mas veces deja de tener sentido buscar tanto Argentina como Alemania

Comment: Me explico mejor con un ejemplo.
Si por ejemplo tengo la misma tabla pero le agrego 15 registros mas que enfrenten a Italia vs Portugal por ejemplo, como determinaría cual es la combinación que mas se repite, siendo que Argentina vs Alemania se repite 11 veces pero Italia vs Portugal se repite 15 veces?

Comment: Y eso aplicado a una base de datos con mas de 1000 combinaciones posibles

Comment: Hola nuevamente, y sí, te voy entendiendo mejor aunque para probar sería mejor tener un ejemplo, no sé si las reglas lo permiten, pero si puedes agrega un archivo de muestra a un drive y comparte por aquí el enlace. Saludos.

Comment: Te paso el link del drive Abraham
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MZdh432O5YCf6r5hbLF-nAZ7yy-KLPIg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: En el ejemplo, a simple vista, parece que el partido que mas se repite es Italy vs Portugal con 12 veces pero si miras mas detenidamente el enfrentamiento se lleva a cabo 14 veces porque al final de la tabla, hay 2 enfrentamientos mas pero esta vez con Portugal como local. Entonces esa parte me confunde demasiado jaja

Comment: La duda basicamente es como lograr que me tire como resultado 14 y no 12

Comment: Me refería al archivo Excel dado que si es una imagen y/o un pdf, tendría que reproducir todo y no tengo tiempo de ello.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1moVSjkTLoedARY0E3T680YvcQR0o2z5a?usp=sharing

Comment: Hola nuevamente. Si no quieres hacerte mucho problema, deberías usar columnas auxiliares, de ese modo sería más fácil.